# How to explain strange behavior of React component with UUID as a key?

Tags: reactjs, key, iterable

I have some React component generating a list. The list contains data fetched from DB , but user can also add new element to the list.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
reservations: Object.values(state.reservationsMap).filter(r => r.weekdayId === ownProps.weekdayId),
projectsMap: state.projectsMap
})

class ReservationListBox extends Component {
render() {
    let reservations = this.props.reservations.map((reservation) => {
        let project = this.props.projectsMap[reservation.projectId];

        let hoursInput;
        return (

            <div key={reservation.id}>
                <div className="btn-group timesheet-project-column">
                    <button type="button"
                            className="btn btn-primary">{project.projectName}</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span className="caret"></span>
                        <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <AvailableProjectsListBox reservationId={reservation.id}/>
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <input ref={ node => {hoursInput = node}} type="text" className="form-control timesheet-hour"
                           value={reservation.hours}
                           onChange={()=> this.props.dispatch(fillHours(reservation.id, hoursInput.value))}/> // when I change value here it works but elements are displayed in different order
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger"
                            onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(removeReservation(reservation.id))}> 
                        <span className="glyphicon  glyphicon-trash img-circle text-danger"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-5">
            {reservations}
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReservationListBox = connect(mapStateToProps)(ReservationListBox);

export default ReservationListBox
```

---- Component where I add element to List is top level component of ReservationListBox (code below)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
weekday: state.weekdaysMap[ownProps.weekdayId]
})

class TimesheetTableRow extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="row timesheet-row">
            <div className="col-lg-1">
                <span>{this.props.weekday.day}/{this.props.weekday.month}/{this.props.weekday.year}</span>
            </div>

            <ReservationListBox weekdayId={this.props.weekday.id}/>

            <div className="col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success"
                        onClick={()=> this.props.onAddReservation(this.props.weekdayId)}>
                    <span className="glyphicon  glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-2">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" className="btn  btn-success" title="Set default">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-time img-circle text-success"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-2">
                <span>{this.props.weekday.statusCode}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

TimesheetTableRow = connect(
mapStateToProps,
{
    onAddReservation: addReservation
}
)
(TimesheetTableRow);

export default TimesheetTableRow
```

as a key (for div) I use long value for reservations fetch from DB and generated UUID for new ones.

Problem:

eg. If I have one element in the list fetched and add two (o more) new ones, and next I provide value for the second (middle) element input field (invoking onChange), React replaces this element with the last one, making the list reordered. The problem does't take place when I generate id as number

// actions where I generate id for new element

```
 import { v4 } from "node-uuid";
 export const addReservation = (weekdayId) => ({
 type: 'ADD_RESERVATION',
 weekdayId,
 reservationId: v4()
 })
```

but this below works correctly , list isn't reordered

```
 var nextId = 100;
 export const addReservation = (weekdayId) => ({
 type: 'ADD_RESERVATION',
 weekdayId,
 reservationId: nextId++
 })
```

Here is a reducer handling ADD_RESEVATION action.

```
const reservationsMap = (state = {}, action = {}) => { 

switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_PROJECT':
        if (!_.hasIn(state, action.reservationId)) {
            return state;
        }
        return createNewReservationState(state, action.reservationId, "projectId", action.selectedProjectId);
    case 'FILL_HOURS':
        if (!_.hasIn(state, action.reservationId)) {
            return state;
        }
        return createNewReservationState(state, action.reservationId, "hours", action.hours);
    case 'ADD_RESERVATION':
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.reservationId]: {
                id: action.reservationId,
                weekdayId: action.weekday.id,
                hours: action.weekday.defaultHoursNumber,
                projectId: action.weekday.defaultProjectId
            }
        };
    case 'REMOVE_RESERVATION':
        if (!_.hasIn(state, action.reservationId)) {
            return state;
        }
        return _.assign({}, _.omit(state, action.reservationId));
    case 'SET_DEFAULT_PROJECT':
        return state;
    default:
        return state;
}
}

const createNewReservationState = (state, id, property, value) => {
let reservation = _.set(_.assign({}, _.pick(state, id)[id]), property, value);
let reservationEntry = _.set(_.assign({}, _.pick(state, id)), id, reservation);
return _.assign({}, _.omit(state, id), reservationEntry);
}
```

SOLUTION:
replacing createNewReservationState and return result:

```
  _.mapValues(state, (value) => {
                if (value.id == action.reservationId) {
                    return {
                        id: value.id,
                        weekdayId: value.weekdayId,
                        hours: action.hours,
                        projectId: value.projectId
                    }

                }
                return value
            }
```

Comment: You haven't shown much of the code relevant to your problem, like how you are generating IDs, what happens with onChange, etc.

Comment: I've added code of both components and action where ID is generated

Comment: I found the source of problem. "createNewReservationState" function after filling input puts modified object as last element of map. My fault  :/